# vue router back browser button

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

At the moment, when I get to the detail page, the ID I need is taken from the url parameters, but if I go to another detail page and try to return to the previous one, the url is not updated and the data is not updated

What needs to be done to change the url ?

or use some native `popstate` or some like this

```
performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')
.map(nav => nav.type)
.includes('back_forward')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using history option with createRouter?

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    ...
})
```

Edit:

I put together a small demo that you can try. On a very basic level, it is simulating router history.

https://codesandbox.io/s/router-history-with-parameters-yv002y

Comment: yes i use it, `createWebHistory`